# Number of entities in FB messenger

Tags: facebook, wit.ai

is it possible to set the parameter of number of entities somehow so when the messages flow through the webhook, there is more than one appended? I can to it with my own `curl` with the `n` parameter, but cannot see anythin in the `wit.ai` app setting for facebook setting.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer on the [FB Developers](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/?fref=nf) page as:

```
Lars Schwarz There are no options you could specify or even change. 
The build-in NLP is only meant as simple integration, 
if you need extended options you need to integrate the calls yourself.
```

Comment: as of now it is possible to change it in Messenger NLP advanced settings